# API deployment to Railway keeps crashing: URI cannot contain options with no value

Tags: mongodb, railway

As the title says.
I've tried to google this line but it brings back like 4 results only and none are useful.

This is how I connect to my mongoDB server

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

mongoose.connect(`${process.env.MONGODB_URI}`);
```

And this is my URI:

```
mongodb+srv://MY_USERNAME:MY_PASSWORD@cluster0.CLUSTER_ID.mongodb.net/ORGANIZATION_NAME?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

And then just require his in my index file.

What am I doing wrong to get this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out.
When copying my URI into Railway's env variables, something went wrong and it only copied the uri up to `retryWrites`, leaving out everything after (`=true&w=majority`). So `retryWrites` was the option with no value it talked about.